# GitLab: Not able to clone repository from GitLab Server via http and ssh

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-7

I am running GitLab Community Edition. I created a one new project in Gitlab. When I try to clone via `http` it says:

> `remote: Not found fatal: repository 'http://myhost/test/sample.git' not found`

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

- https://YOUR_USER_NAME@myhost/test/sample.git

or

- https://YOUR_USER_NAME:PASSWORD@myhost/test/sample.git

most of the time there is a problem with authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Is that url valid? It probably should have `https` rather than `http`.

Go to the web interface of your GitLab server and copy the `HTTPS` or `SSH` url from there.